# Using a DependencyProperty ChangedCallback as a validation measure

Tags: c#, wpf

I have an `UserControl` where I declare two `DependencyProperties`

```
int? Level;
CardBase SelectedCardBase;
```

A non-null `CardBase` object will always have 2 read-only `integers`: `MinLevel` and `MaxLevel`.

The `UserControl` allows the user to change as he desires both DPs, and the internal logic must ensure that both DPs have valid values following these rules:

- If `SelectedCardBase` is null, then `Level` must be null.
- If `SelectedCardBase` is not null, then `Level` must be between `MinLevel` and `MaxLevel`.
- When `SelectedCardBase` changes to anything but `null`, `Level` is set to `MaxLevel`.

This is the code:

```
    public CardBase SelectedCardBase
    {
        get { return (CardBase)GetValue(SelectedCardBaseProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SelectedCardBaseProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedCardBaseProperty = 
         DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedCardBase", typeof(CardBase), typeof(MyUserControl), 
         new PropertyMetadata(null, new PropertyChangedCallback(SelectedCardBaseChanged)));        

    private static void SelectedCardBaseChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.NewValue == null)
            d.SetValue(LevelProperty, null);
        else
            d.SetValue(LevelProperty, ((CardBase)e.NewValue).MaxLevel);
    }

    public int? Level
    {
        get { return (int?)GetValue(LevelProperty); }
        set { SetValue(LevelProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty LevelProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Level", typeof(int?), typeof(MyUserControl), 
        new PropertyMetadata(null, new PropertyChangedCallback(LevelChanged)));
    private static void LevelChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        CardBase card = (CardBase)d.GetValue(SelectedCardBaseProperty);

        if (card == null)
        {
            if (e.NewValue != null)
                d.SetValue(LevelProperty, null);
        }
        else if (e.NewValue == null)
        {
            d.SetValue(LevelProperty, e.OldValue);
        }
        else
        {
            int level = (int)e.NewValue;

            if (level < card.MinLevel)
                d.SetValue(LevelProperty, card.MinLevel);
            else if (level > card.MaxLevel)
                d.SetValue(LevelProperty, card.MaxLevel);
        }
    }
```

I don't fully get how `CoerceValueCallbacks` work, and I've read (or misunderstood) that both Coerce and Changed callbacks can be overwritten because they are metadata, so my questions are:

- What problems (if they exist) will I have when something subscribes to the OnValueChanged of one of those DP?
- Should I use CoerceValueCallbacks instead of this?
- If so, what is the correct way of doing this using CoerceValueCallbacks?
- And of course, with the given rules at the beginning, there is any mistake on the  code that would cause strange behaviour, or anything that could be improved?

Comment: Why are you using ChangedCallback for validation when `DependencyPropertyManager.Register` has an explicit override for providing a Validation callback? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms597501(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @NickUdell precisely because I'm still learning the ropes of the DP system and some details get out of my knowledge. What should I do then, register them on the constructor of the usercontrol?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should use `CoerceValueCallback` instead to coerce your Level property (what you are trying to do is not "validation" strictly speaking).

```
private static object CoerceLevel(DependencyObject d, object value)
{
    var control = (MyUserControl)d;
    if (control.SelectedCard == null) return null;
    var level = (int?)value;
    if (level.HasValue) 
    { 
        return Math.Min(Math.Max(level.Value, control.SelectedCard.MinLevel), control.SelectedCard.MaxLevel);
    }
    else
    {
        return control.Level;
        //or 
        //return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: Will this be called automatically whenever the Level is set?

Comment: @GuillermoMestre, yes, if you add this calllback to your dependency property declaration.

Comment: And the CardChangedCallback should remain as it is, right?

Comment: @GuillermoMestre, pretty much, yes. You should use `PropertyChangedCallback`, when you want to change other proprties, and `CoerceValueCallback` when you want to alter the changed property itself. You might want to cast first argument to `MyUserControl` and use regular properties though. `d.SetValue` calls do not look pretty.

Comment: @GuillermoMestre, you can read more on msdn https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745795%28v=vs.110%29.aspx